Can a floppy disk be wiped securely using the Windows format command with the passes-parameter?
Does the /P:<count> parameter of the Windows format command securely erase (wipe) all data of a 3.5" floppy disk? Meaning, the data is unrecoverable? If so, is 3 passes sufficient for the data to be entirely irrecoverable?
I currently am planning to use: format A: /fs:fat /P:3 /y /U. /U apparently being undocumented for 'unconditional format'.
If not, what other Windows 10/11 command line tools can I use for securely wiping floppy disks?

The data being unrecovrable by whom using which equipment? A casual user will not be able to recover anything after a plain unconditional format anyway. A determined data archivist or government agency with expensive tools and equipment might be.

'Unrecoverable' as in 'unrecoverable' by anyone despite the tools or budget available.

IDK about Windows command line tools, but a good pair of tin snips can quickly make a diskette unreadable by most equipment. If that's not sufficiently secure, consider tossing the diskette on a camp fire.

Although those are fun ways of data destruction it kind of missed the point of it being reusable afterwards :).

If you want to reuse the floppies, you should consider getting a hardware bulk magnetic eraser that treats the media as a whole, rather than having any implicit organization. Otherwise, take them to your local shredder.

If you trust NIST "guidelines", no matter what the media, the only way to make the data unrecoverable to to physically shred into pieces no large than 0.25 inch. Reusing media is not an option.

If it is absolutely critical that the data not be read, I'd be inclined to take the diskette all the way to Mordor and cast it the Crack of Doom.

How secure do you want it? There aren't two options, "secure" and "not secure". It's a whole range of relative levels of security.

@WillHartung floppies (3.5" at least) contain a steel window cap. Could be dangerous in a magnetic eraser.

Using a good magnet will definitely hack things good on that floppy. However, on 3.5" "floppies", that magnet will probably magnetize the metal cover too - depending on the size and strength of the magnet, and the technique used. While it is doable to remove the metal protection before the magnetization if you want to erase only one disk (and reapply it later), it might be daunting to do it for all the 15000 floppies of your secret organization :)

The linked page says the /P switch will first write zeros across the disk, and subsequent passes will write a random number in each pass. So just do the one pass and then write random data across the disk, instead of a single random value. That's going to make it harder to distinguish residual traces of data.

@SimonCrase: Nah, better to go all "Into the fiery orb with ye!" on them.

While the metal shutter could potentially be removed and replaced, as virolino says, 3½" floppies also have a metal hub.  Is that likely to be steel too?  It would be a lot harder to remove and replace that without damaging the disk itself.

I wouldn't expect the hub or shutter to really pose a problem, since they're made out of materials that can't be made into particularly strong magnets.  It would probably be better to bulk-erase media using an alternating magnetic field (such as that produced by a bulk tape eraser) rather than a strong neodymium magnet, since the alternating field would leave the metal parts of the disk without any dominant magnetic orientation, but I doubt the soft steel could be permanently magnetized strongly enough to matter.

FWIW most computers don’t even have floppy drives anymore so practically speaking a floppy is reasonably secure simply from obsolescence. So your baseline security level is already pretty good without doing anything.

@bob I understand your point but I disagree here. That's the equivalent of saying in a hypothetical world full of self-driving cars only: pedestrians don't need to look around anymore when crossing a road. Human drivers are gone so there due to removed (driver) human error risk we can just go and walk without looking. The obsolescence of floppy drives is overrated because one can stilly buy a readily available (USB) floppy drive for a few bucks anywhere. Despite the question is about how to format in a secure way, not about if we should.

Yes you can buy a reader, but risk to data means the likelihood someone can and will access the data. In the 90s for a floppy the answer would be “very high” because most people who found it would have easy and zero cost access to a floppy drive to read it. Today? Most people don’t have a floppy drive, many wouldn’t know you can buy one, and the ones who did would have to care enough to fork over the $10 USD to do so. Plus I’d bet many people today wouldn’t even recognize a floppy disk to know what it is. Understand what the question is, just a frame challenge as to the need for the question.

(I know the USB readers are cheap but since most people no longer use floppies and the old ones are unlikely to still have in tact data on them not to mention difficulty using the data b/c many old programs are obsolete, and I’m not sure most people would value any data on a disk they happen to find at $10 USD. Some random curious person might, but it’s a low risk IMO unless the disk contains highly sensitive data written recently)

@virolino   Not all floppies have a steel shutter.  Several brands used aluminum and I have a whole box of them with plastic shutters. In any case, if you care, then just spin the disk in its sleeve and keep the magnet away from the shutter.

@Perkins: Aluminum sounds reasonable. But I never saw (not even in pictures on the internet) a floppy with a plastic shutter. Tnx for teaching me smth today.

@virolino I think they were the very last box of floppies I ever bought before they disappeared.  I think around 2008.  And I know for a fact that it was after 2002.  One of the last innovations in the medium I expect, unless you count the ZIP and Jazz drives that were essentially the same thing, just with more protection.

I take "secure" data deletion here in the sense of "not able to be recovered by common software undelete tools". There is the forensic approach which could try to recover deleted data by analysing the disk with electron microscopes and other high-tech equipment - I don't have data on success rates though.
"Secure erase data" or "wipe" effect can be achieved by overwriting all data once (with zeroes or other values). Paranoid levels can incorporate several passes with alternating and randomized bit patterns (7 levels of overwriting according to NIST recommendations on cryptographic secure deletion, finishing with random data to be indistinguishable from encrypted data; Related interesting read: NIST media sanitization).
According to Microsoft's documentation on format, the /P passes parameter really does control overwriting all data prior to formatting. So it should be a good to go approach with 1 pass for "sufficient private data erasing security level" or "reset data area to quasi unused state" (this means setting /P to 0; higher numbers define subsequent overwrite passes with random numbers).
Sidenote: Using format only and possibly with the "quick format" option will not erase data on the disk automatically! It merely just rewrites the disk geometry information and a new file table which contains addresses of the file contents only. Therefore the original data can still be read in bulk and undelete programs can recognize the beginning of a file by header information ("Magic Number") and other indicators. Check Recuva for example if you want to test the "undeleteability" of formatted or wiped disks/data.
Other tools to overwrite securely on file level (also covering empty/unused space, memory caches, etc. on FAT and NTFS) can be found in the sysinternals suite tool secure delete (sdelete). Another default program on Windows machines is the diskpart command line tool also allowing full disk erasing only like format.
For non-Microsoft tools, you could resort to dd on GNU/Linux machines or programs that allow disk partitions access (PartitionWizard, gparted and the like). Some tools shipped with SSDs also allow secure deletion of data (also on other drives than the SSD).

Why specifically with zero data, what is so special about it? Zero data encoded as MFM data stream by the floppy controller for the write head is just a sequence of pulses with timing between them resembling  toggling the magnetic polarity, just like any other data byte pattern. For example, commonly used pattern when formatting floppies is to fill the sector with F6h for some reason, not 00h.

@Justme: If drive heads don't produce a strong enough field to saturate the entire thickness of the disk media, using multiple passes of random data while randomly varying the field strength may make data recovery harder than a single pass with a field strength that's almost sufficient to penetrate the media, but a single pass with a higher signal strength would be better yetr.

@Justme Zeroing is just an arbitrary choice. In terms of bit values you only have the choice between "one" or "zero", where zero is associated more to "nothing/empty/wiped". Any of those values will do. Also alternating, randomizing using a byte-wide pattern etc. once will do (and repeating overwriting that multiple times will of course also do).

@supercat That might be true, agreed. Would be something specific to floppy disk drives. Thinking of the "double sided" writing of 5,25" floppies this would be an indicator that writing one side does not penetrate the whole thickness. On the other hand, writing one side does not imply an "imprint" of that on the other side either, so if there is residual signal of former data, it would be somewhere "inside" the thickness of the media and probably too faint to be restorable by commonly available means - that is, possible only by electron microsocopes tech-level.

@Antares The tech you're looking for is called a "magnetic force microscope", and yes, it is sometimes possible to recover previous bits from a magnetic disk by using one.  Hence why NIST recommends multiple overwrites for really sensitive data. But unless you think someone is going to be willing to spend tens of thousands of dollars to scrounge 1.44MB of data (or maybe 2.88 if it's one of the really fancy floppies) then just writing one complete pass of something is probably sufficient.

On a typical floppy drive, the erase head is wider than the read/write head, and is designed in such a way that all of the magnetic domains that pass under it will be forced to the same orientation, regardless of how they may have been oriented previously.  There may be areas of the disk between tracks which are not completely scrubbed by the erase head, but these would be unlikely to ever receive data when written by a properly calibrated drive using the same track spacing, and would be invisible to any stock drive which has been calibrated for standard track placement.  When using 5.25" disks, a 1.2MB drive may be unable to completely erase a disk formatted for use on 360K drives, and a 360K drive may be unable to erase half of the tracks on a 1.2MB formatted disk, but such issues should not arise when using 3.5" disks formatted for 720K or 1.44MB capacity, since all such drives use the same track spacing.

Thank you. That's interesting but it doesn't answer my question if this method is the right one for secure erasure.

It brings up a question whether any technique that's designed for the high level floppy interface can be considered secure. The premise being that if disk drives can drift on alignment, and the programs can only change data based on that alignment, then lingering data can be left behind on the media surface. Inaccessible to standard programs, but not necessarily to specialized techniques. So the real question isn't whether the P parameter is enough, it's whether anything is enough save for a custom program driving the head with much finer control.

@BobOrtiz: If the goal is to erase information which was written in normal fashion by a calibrated drive of the same type, one low-level formatting pass will be sufficient when using a floppy drive that was designed in typical fashion.  If the goal is to guard against the possibility that someone used modified hardware to conceal information on a disk for retrieval using modified hardware, even a thousand formatting passes could leave data behind in areas of the disk normal drives would never use.

Is there really the erase head? Isn't the main head creating not enough magnetic field strength to completely re-magnetize the film on the disk?

@lvd Typically there is a separate erase head, yes. Both on tapes and floppy disks.

@lvd: Using a separate erase head makes drives far more tolerant of imperfect calibration.  Hard drives have servo-controlled calibration to follow special tracks written by the factory, so they may not need to use a separate erase head, but having an empty zone around tracks means it doesn't matter if one edge of the drive reaches out past the edge of a track into the empty zone.

Here is an image showing the erase and write heads and their size difference.

@jpa so it works like the following: erase heads remove noise (or demagnetize the film) outside the main track written by R/W head?

@lvd I must admit that I don't know. I presume the erase head clears a wide track, and RW head writes a narrow track on top.

To your required level of security :

'Unrecoverable' as in 'unrecoverable' by anyone despite the tools or budget available.

The answer is simply no. No level of formatting a floppy in a drive can make it completely unrecoverable when examined with infinite amount of budget spend on tools and labour in a data forensic lab looking at the magnetic particles. It just gets harder and harder at each step but not impossible.
However, to prevent reading the contents in a standard floppy drive in a standard system, a single unconditional format pass is fine.

It simply gets impossible after reaching Curie point since ferromagnetism is basically completely disappears at that point. Or, in simpler words, just burn the floppy and you're done :)

@lvd Sure but shredding or heating the floppy was not a part of the original question, just formatting it.

It can't be literally no level, can it? There has to be a point where you've performed enough passes that whatever residual orientation is left is physically indistinguishable from random noise, doesn't there?

@Idran Yeah, the infinities don't work well in a practical scenario. The floppy likely wears out and turns unwritable in addition to being unreadable at some point in normal systems. But the budget for data forensics was infinite. Maybe there is residual magnetism slightly out of reach of the erase head which can't clear wide enough area of the track or deep enough depth into the material. Magnetic material always has hysteresis unless the field is strong enough to bring it to saturation.

Truly secure erasure could be only achieved by increasing temperature above the Curie point so that every piece of ferromagnetic substance in the film on the disk would completely demagnetize.
Apart from that, even the bulk demagnetizer can leave slightly differently magnetized particles which might be enough in theory to restore the information.
The NIST approach of shredding the floppy disk itself is theoretically vulnerable too to successful piece matching and reconstruction.

This would be a cool mod project for a floppy drive

DOS floppy format always writes zeroes in the sector data; only HDDs allowed formatting just the data structures.
And "secure" means "secure today," not "Geordie and Data can't crack it in the 23rd century."

The question was about Windows, not DOS, and are you sure DOS formats floppies with zeroes, because usually it has formatted F6h instead of zero?

I'm definitely not sure DOS formats floppies with a full overwrite of anything since I do recall formatting taking several seconds rather than the several minutes necessary to write the whole disk, and DOS unformat tools were a thing, at least as of MS-DOS 6.22
